# Send Key value form data using post request in Python

Tags: python, post

I am able to make Post request using postMan and I get correct data but when I send the same using python ,I get a different output .
As you can see below using postMan when I make a request I can see the desired output . 
[image]

But when I do the same using my below python code ,it doesn't give me the desired output and overall just gives me the a HTML text with fields filled up ,seems it makes a Get request ,not sure If am sending my form incorrectly

```
def checkDate(self):
        values ={'numberItems':1,
            'mode':'DriveTest',
            'officeId':592,
            'requestedTask':'DT',
            'firstName':'xxx',
            'lastName':'xxx',
            'dlNumber':'xxx',
            'birthMonth':05,
            'birthDay':31,
            'birthYear':123,
            'resetCheckFields':'true'}    
        r = requests.post('https://www.dmv.ca.gov/wasapp/foa/findDriveTest.do',params=values)
        tet=r.text
        print(tet)
```

The actual page is https://www.dmv.ca.gov/wasapp/foa/findDriveTest.do ,so here what I am trying to do is create a script which will run every 4 hours to notify me that a early date is now available .

Answer (score 0):

To make a POST request you should pass your values like this:

```
r = request.post('https://www.dmv.ca.gov/wasapp/foa/findDriveTest.do',data=values)
```

The reason that your previous code didn't make a POST request is that you were trying to pass your values as URL parameters which is used when making a GET request

Comment: I did the same,but still it gives me output as GET result

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
import json
r = requests.post('https://www.dmv.ca.gov/wasapp/foa/findDriveTest.do',params=json.dumps(values), headers = {"content-type": "application/json"})
tet=r.text
print(tet)
```

Comment: You can try by appending `/` at the end of the URL in your code.

Comment: Also check when you are sending data through Postman there are any headers attached with the call or not.